# Can a service principal create other service principals in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I found a link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) which says:

> There is no way to directly create a service principal using the Azure portal. When you register an application through the Azure portal, an application object and service principal are automatically created in your home directory or tenant.

My question is, Can a 'service principal' create another 'service principals' in Azure? If yes, how? and what all permissions required for this?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: The very article you linked to says you should use Managed Identities instead of Service Principals, where possible - is that something you've looked-at, at least?

Comment: Thanks I will check. However, managed identities are used for internal applications. However, I guess the service principles are for external applications.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. Azure AD has no concept of "external" and "internal" applications.  Azure AD does require a slightly different registration process for multi-tenant applications, but multi-tenant applications are not necessarily "internal" or external - nor vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service principal can create another service principal after being assigned  either the corresponding MS Graph permission, or Azure AD role

### MS Graph Permissions

Either of the permissions

`Application.ReadWrite.All`

`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`

**References**

[Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-4)

[Create application API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Create servicePrincipal API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

### Azure AD Role

Any role with one of these permissions

`microsoft.directory/applications/create`

`microsoft.directory/applications/createAsOwner`

`microsoft.directory/applications/allProperties/allTasks`

**Built-in roles**

- Application Administrator
- Application Developer
- Cloud Application Administrator
- Global Administrator
- Hybrid Identity Administrator

**References**

[Azure AD built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference)

[Application registration permissions for custom roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-available-permissions)

Comment: Hello @scottwtang, I tried exactly this but it doesn't seem to work. 

The SP that should create other SP's is assigned Cloud Application Administrator role. 
I log in via:
`az login --service-principal -u <appId> -p <PW> --tenant <tenantId>`
then execute: 
`az ad sp create-for-rbac --verbose`

an application registration gets created, but "/addPassword" fails to create a client secret with 403 "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

I also added the "Application.ReadWrite.All" to the creating service principal but that doesn't seem to change anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PauLy Sorry I'm not able to reproduce your issue. The [AddPassword API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) requires the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission, which is included with the Cloud Application Administrator role. Are you manually calling the AddPassword endpoint? `az ad sp create-for-rbac --verbose` creates the SP and adds the secret in the same run, so there shouldn't be any issue there

Comment: My issue was that the role was scoped to the app registration only, but it would of course need the directory wide permissions. Thanks for helping!